# Creating in memory test server for Microsoft echo bot

Tags: c#, unit-testing, server, botframework

> My intention is to unit test the bot framework project using one of the unit test projects. In the unit test project(MS unit test), I created the test server and tried to access the bot. Now I am not sure whether the test sever and the client is created successfully and with which host(I see it's hosted at localhost at port 80).

When through the console app I call BuildWebHost(args).Run()  in the main method, the server is up and running at localhost at port 5000. I can access http//localhostt:5000/api/messages through bot emulator.

The test server that I created in MS unit test project works fine to call .net core api.

> I am not sure whether the test server can host the bot project and expose directline API.

```
    using EchoBot;// Bot project refernce
    using WebApiDotnetCore;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System;

     namespace MSUnitTestProject
    {
       class TestClientProvider:IDisposable
     {
    private TestServer server;
    public HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }
    public TestClientProvider()
    {
        //IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseContentRoot(@"C:\Local\NETI\InMemoryServer\MyBotProjects\EchoBot")
        //                          .UseEnvironment("development").UseStartup<EchoBot.Startup>()
        //   .UseApplicationInsights()


        //IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<WebApiDotnetCore.Startup>();
        IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<EchoBot.Startup>();
        server = new TestServer(builder);
        httpClient = server.CreateClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        server.Dispose();
        httpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

> Unit test project

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task BotTestMethod()
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/messages");
        HttpStatusCode code = response.StatusCode;
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Assert.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK, code);

    }
```

Comment: Thread from git https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1253#event-1934022703